# How to rescan and remount drives on Ubuntu Hardy or Jaunty?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, mount, storage, udev

When I connect an USB drive to an Ununtu Hardy and Jaunty system, the system mounts the partitions found on the drive, and opens a Nautilus window for each mounted partitions. Within Nautilus, I am able to unmount partitions.

What I need is a command or action which forces the system to rescan the available drives and partitions, and automount each not mounted partition, including those which I've manually unmounted from Nautilus. `sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart` or ... `reload` doesn't do this.

As of now, I just unplug the USB drive, and commect it again, which will force a scan and a mount on that drive. But I want to do force the rescan and remount without unplugging anything, preferably without the user having the know device or drive names.

Answer (score 3):

Try triggering the add rule to udev.
The default action is add. ( probably what you want)

```
# udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=block
```

you can call

```
# udevadm settle --timeout=60
```

to wait for udev to finish doing it's thing. (in this case 60 seconds, default is 180seconds)

Comment: Sorry, neither of these commands work. After trying them, and waiting for something to happen, and giving up, I had to disconnect the USB cable, and connect it again to make `udev` recognize the device. Do you have a command which you have tried and it works?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo unmount -a` and `sudo mount -a` will do the job,but only if the device is not busy(in use).
All  of  the  file systems described in /etc/mtab are mounted or unmounted.But after I tried it with USB,It turned out be OK.

Comment: You wrote twice "mount". Did you mean one of them to be "unmount"?

Comment: I am sorry,that is a typo.I have corrected it.

Comment: I can't accept this answer, because it has a side effect that it umounts already mounted partitions. I need a solution which doesn't touch existing mounts.

Comment: Note that the command to unmount is mistyped, it's actually **umount**